# How to Add a Custom Google Search to a Website with Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)

Tags: javascript, php, amp-html

I am trying to use the code I have my Google Custom Search Engine (GCSE) code:

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=009000000000000:u0000000"></script>
<div class="gcse-searchbox"></div>
<div class="gcse-searchresults"></div>
```

However, my Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) site does not allow me to add JavaScript to it, and I don't see any AMP components that allow GCSE to be integrated into an AMP site.

How can I get GCSE on my site without breaking AMP compliance?
Can you think of any ideas?